# Python3 telnetlib - telnet with username and password and then execute other commands

Tags: python-3.x, telnetlib

I would like to be able to telnet, input login and password credentials and then execute commands once connected but my code seems to not continue after password is entered.

```
import getpass
import telnetlib

HOST = "172.25.1.1"
user = input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until(b"login: ")
tn.write(user.encode('utf-8') + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('utf-8') + "\n")

tn.write(b"command to be issued")
print(tn.read_all())
```

with this code I want to telnet, input login credentials, input password, and once connected issue a command

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was a timing issue, I needed to `import time` and add `time.sleep(2)` after issuing the command before `print(tn.read_all())`.